# Is Class SubClass or Object

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Note: I'm asking about subclasses, not derived classes.

Basically, what I need to do is check properties of an object and look for those that have a specific attribute set.

The problem I have is that a lot of the properties are from subclasses

```
public class ExampleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public object Whatever { get; set; }
}

public class MiddleEarth
{
    [Example]
    public Type EntityType { get; set; }
}

public class Elf : MiddleEarth
{
    [Example]
    public SubClass ItsLateAndImTired { get; set; }

    public IList<Arg> Args { get; set; }

    //Need to check properties of this object as well
    public class SubClass
    {
        public object SubProperty { get; set; }

        [Example]
        public object SubPropertyWithAttribute { get; set; }
    }

    public class Arg
    {
        [Example]
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to do it as follows...but for reasons noted in the comments it won't work

```
public List<string> IterateProperties(object _o)
{
    List<string> problems = new List<string>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo info in _o.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        //All 3 of these will return the exact same thing
        Type thisType = this.GetType();
        Type oType = _o.GetType();
        Type infoType = info.ReflectedType;

        //IsSubClassOf only checks for derived classes, 
        //so it's not the method I'm looking for
        if (info.ReflectedType.IsSubclassOf(this.GetType()))
        {
            object sub = info.GetValue(_o, null);
            if (sub != null)
            {
                problems.AddRange(this.IterateProperties(sub));
            }
        }

        object[] attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExampleAttribute), true);
        foreach (object o in attributes)
        {
            if (info.GetValue(_o, null) == null)
            {
                problems.Add(String.Format("Attribute {0} in class {1} cannot be null", info.Name, info.ReflectedType.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }

    return problems;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since when is an "elf" a "middle earth"? I would expect "elf" to be "humanoid".

Comment: @zzzzBov: ItsLateAndHesTired

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, then I would expect him to take a nap...ZEN FIRE ZE MISSILES!

Comment: @zzzzBov Yeah, it wasn't my best work. See Pieter's comment...I was doing a lot of things that didn't make a whole lot of sense by that point yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `Type.GetNestedTypes()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/493t6h7t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but think that GetProperties method got some flags that can help...